# What do I need to do to preserve sda2 and sda4 paritions, and format sda3 for Ubuntu and part of it as swap area?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

Been figuring out how to replace my windows 8 with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for three hours now, and I need help.

I have reached the point where I need to select a partition where to install ubuntu.

I have 4 partitions in my pc:

sda1 100mb. Allocated for the system. Prev made by Windows

sda2 20000mb

sda3 52000mb

sda4 40000mb

I want to install ubuntu in sda3 partition to replace windows 8.

I don't want sda2 and sda4 partitions to be formatted as I have important files saved on those partitions.

What I did is I edited sda3 partition to be the ext4 "/". I was planning to make 4000mb of it to be "swap area" but I can't as the remaining 4000mb is marked with 'Unusable' after editing the sda3 partition.

What's going on here and what do I need to do to preserve sda2 and sda4 paritions, and format sda3 for Ubuntu and part of it as swap area?

Comment: upload the gparted screenshot to imgur.com and then paste the link here.

Comment: Hi Already solved my problem. I maxed out the number of primary partitions so I can't create a new primary one for the 'swap area'. I just made two new logical partitions. Poof! Solved it. :)

Comment: if you solved it,then delete this question.

Comment: Or answer it so that others with your problem can benefit. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The OP solved it and posted the solution in the comments.

> I maxed out the number of primary partitions so I can't create a new
>   primary one for the 'swap area'. I just made two new logical
>   partitions.